# Loop and array and sub array

Tags: mysql, php, json

I am working on a script that needs to loop an array and loop a sub array. I want to take in rows from a table (that piece works fine) that look like:

```
invoice | item
inv1    | it_A
inv1    | it_C
inv2    | it_D
inv2    | it_B
inv3    | it_A
```

and display the JSON (also works) like pseudo code

```
inv1

   it_C
   it_D

inv2

   it_D
   it_B

inv3

   it_A
```

but I have the loop wrong, thanks for any assistance

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

echo "rows found";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$invid = $row[invoice_number];
echo $invid;



foreach($invid as $invoicelines)
{

$sql1 = $invoicelines[item_code];



echo $sql1;
```

Comment: Wrong site; DBAs don't do loops.

Comment: However in pure MySQL [JSON_ARRAYAGG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) will get you the result you desire.

Comment: @mustaccio as DBA humour, your comment made me smile. However it is incorrect. Oracle has PL/SQL, MS SQL Server has T-SQL, PostgreSQL has PL/pgSQL and MySQL has, well, what it has - all of which perform loops. Most DBAs have, at the very least, notions of these languages and can and do write code using them. [Lateral joins](https://heap.io/blog/engineering/postgresqls-powerful-new-join-type-lateral) are a form of loop as indeed are [Recursive CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900055/is-sql-or-even-tsql-turing-complete)s (which made SQL Turing complete) can be used as looping constructs.

Comment: I'm voting to migrate this question over to StackOverflow as it is more related to a problem withing your PHP and not the data or underlying storage engine.

Answer (score 0):

Using the SQL will get you the invoice and json aggregated items in an array:

```
SELECT invoice, JSON_ARRAYAGG(item)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY invoice
```